# How to disable basic authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, basic-authentication

Is there anyway to disable basic authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API? I have a requirement to disable it, considering it is a very weak authentication strategy.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you use asp.net core web api instead of asp.net web api? It seems there is no basic authentication in asp.net core

Comment: @Rena, yes I'm using .net core